# Interpretation of a combinatorial identity involving iterated binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I am trying to find an combinatorial interpretation for the following combinatorial identity involving iterated binomial coefficients, which appeared in the November 1980 edition of The American Math Monthly:

$\dbinom{\binom{n}{b}}{2}=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^b\dbinom{\binom{b}{j}+e_j}{2}\binom{n+b-j}{2b},$

where $e_j=\frac{1+(-1)^{j+1}}{2}$, that is, $e_j=1$ if $j$ is odd, and $0$ otherwise.

Essentially, the left hand side of the identity can be interpreted as the number of ways to choose 2 $b$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. What I am interested in is the derivation of the right hand side of the identity; I have read the proof in The American Math Monthly, and the author mentioned that the expression $\binom{n+b-j}{2b}$ refers to the selection of $2b$ objects from the original set $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, augmented by the adjunction of $b-j$ "jokers", where $0\leq j\leq b-1$, to allow for the fact that the intersection of two distinct $b$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ can have a minimum and a maximum cardinality of $0$ and $b-1$ respectively.

What I am struggling to understand here is the expression $\dbinom{\binom{b}{j}+e_j}{2}$; how does one interpret this expression? Alternatively, is there any other way for which one can prove the identity? Personally, I have proven via a combination of combinatorial and algebraic methods that the identity does hold for small values of $b$, but the expression is not that tractable for large values of $b$.

Comment: $$\dbinom{\binom{b}{j}+e_j}{2}$$
can be expressed as
$$\frac{1}{8} \left(-2 \binom{b}{j}+(-1)^j-1\right) \left(-2 \binom{b}{j}+(-1)^j+1\right)$$
The whole expression can also be expressed in the form of hypergeometric functions.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we seek to evaluate (the term for $j=0$ is zero)
$$\frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{j=0}^b \left({b\choose j} + e_j\right)
\left({b\choose j} + e_j-1\right)
{n+b-j\choose 2b}.$$

This sum has four components, call them $A,B,C$ and $D.$

We have
$$A = \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{j=0}^{b/2} {b\choose 2j}^2 {n+b-2j\choose 2b},$$
and
$$B = - \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{j=0}^{b/2} {b\choose 2j} {n+b-2j\choose 2b},$$
and 
$$C = \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{j=0}^{b/2} {b\choose 2j+1}^2 {n+b-2j-1\choose 2b},$$
and finally
$$D = \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{j=0}^{b/2} {b\choose 2j+1} {n+b-2j-1\choose 2b}.$$

Starting with $A$ we put  (we will use this substitution several times
with different values of $b$ and $j$)

$${b\choose 2j}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+z)^b}{z^{2j+1}} \; dz$$

to get for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+z)^b}{z}
\sum_{j=0}^{b/2} {b\choose 2j} {n+b-2j\choose 2b}
\frac{1}{z^{2j}} \; dz.$$

For the inner sum we get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n+b}}{w^{2b+1}}
\sum_{j=0}^{b/2} {b\choose 2j} \frac{1}{z^{2j}(1+w)^{2j}}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n+b}}{w^{2b+1}}
\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{z(1+w)}\right)^b
+ \left(1-\frac{1}{z(1+w)}\right)^b\right) \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1} z^b}
\left(\left(z+zw+1\right)^b
+ \left(z+zw-1\right)^b\right) \; dw
.$$

This lets us evaluate $B$ which has $z=1$ to obtain
$$-\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1}}
\left(\left(w+2\right)^b
+ \left(w\right)^b\right) \; dw.$$

We get for $C$ the integral
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+z)^b}{z}
\sum_{j=0}^{b/2} {b\choose 2j+1} {n+b-2j-1\choose 2b}
\frac{1}{z^{2j+1}} \; dz.$$

The inner sum here evaluates to
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1} z^b}
\left(\left(z+zw+1\right)^b
- \left(z+zw-1\right)^b\right) \; dw
.$$

This lets us evaluate $D$ which has $z=1$ to obtain
$$+\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1}}
\left(\left(w+2\right)^b
- \left(w\right)^b\right) \; dw.$$

It follows that $B+D$ is
$$-\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1}} w^b\; dw
= -\frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}.$$

On the other hand $A+C$ is
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+z)^b}{z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1} z^b}
\left(z+zw+1\right)^b \; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+z)^b}{z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1}}
\left(\frac{1+z}{z}+w\right)^b \; dw \; dz.$$

This is
$$\frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+z)^b}{z}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} 
\left(\frac{1+z}{z}\right)^q w^{b-q} \; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} 
\frac{(1+z)^{b+q}}{z^{q+1}} w^{b-q} \; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{2b+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} {b+q\choose q} w^{b-q} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} {b+q\choose q} 
\frac{(1+w)^{n}}{w^{b+q+1}} \; dw.$$

This finally yields
$$\frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} {b+q\choose q} {n\choose b+q}
= \frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q}
\frac{n!}{b!q!(n-b-q)!}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q}
\frac{(n-b)!}{q!(n-b-q)!}
= \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} {n-b\choose q}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+v)^{n-b}}{v}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} \frac{1}{v^q} \; dv
\\ = \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+v)^{n-b}}{v}
\left(1+\frac{1}{v}\right)^b \; dv
\\ = \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+v)^{n}}{v^{b+1}} \; dv
= \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}^2.$$

The conclusion is that
$$A+B+C+D
= \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}^2
- \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
= \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\left({n\choose b}-1\right),$$

which was to be shown.

Another instance of the Egorychev method is at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664823/).

**Addendum Tue Apr 14 21:38:00 CEST 2015.**
As per the comments we can evaluate $B+D$ as follows.
$$B+D = -\frac{1}{2}
\sum_{j=0}^b {b\choose j} (-1)^j {n+b-j\choose 2b}.$$

Using the standard integral substitution from above this yields
$$-\frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+v)^{n+b}}{v^{2b+1}}
\sum_{j=0}^b {b\choose j} (-1)^j \frac{1}{(1+v)^j}\; dv
\\ = -\frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+v)^{n+b}}{v^{2b+1}}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+v}\right)^b \; dv
\\ = -\frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+v)^{n+b}}{v^{2b+1}}
\left(\frac{v}{1+v}\right)^b \; dv
\\ = -\frac{1}{2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+v)^{n}}{v^{b+1}} \; dv
= -\frac{1}{2}{n\choose b}.$$

Comment: I quite like your solution of using complex analytic methods to prove the identity. However, I do realise that all we want to show is that $\sum_{j=0}^b\binom{b}{j}^2\binom{n+b-j}{2b}=\binom{n}{b}^2$ and $\sum_{j=0}^b(-1)^{j+1}\binom{b}{j}\binom{n+b-j}{2b}=\binom{n}{b}$. Out of curiosity more than anything else, is there a combinatorial way of proving these identities?

Comment: Nice and clear presentation! +1

Comment: It is not as simple as it could be, but I leave additional simplification to the reader.

Comment: The two identities mentioned in @yoshi's comment above have since been corrected and proved at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234156/combinatorial-interpretation-of-identity-sum-limits-j-0b-binombj2-bin . (Just adding this comment for future readers' sake.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an  answer using formal power series that  is somewhat simpler
than the first one. We start as before:

$$\frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{j=0}^b \left({b\choose j} + e_j\right)
\left({b\choose j} + e_j-1\right)
{n+b-j\choose 2b}$$

where we have $e_j = [[j\;\text{is odd}]].$

Expanding we get three pieces, the first is

$$A = \frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{j=0}^b {b\choose j}^2
{n+b-j\choose 2b},$$

the second is

$$B = \frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{j=0}^b 
{b\choose j} (2e_j-1)
{n+b-j\choose 2b}
= \frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{j=0}^b 
{b\choose j} (-1)^{j+1}
{n+b-j\choose 2b} 
$$

and the third

$$C = \sum_{j=0}^b 
e_j (e_j-1)
{n+b-j\choose 2b} =0,$$

which leaves  $A$ and $B.$ Starting  with $A$ we observe  that we must
have $n\ge b$ or else the  third binomial coefficient vanishes for all
$j$ in the range, making for a zero contribution. We find

$$\frac{1}{2} 
\sum_{j=0}^b {b\choose j} [z^{b-j}] (1+z)^b
[w^{n-b-j}] (1+w)^{n+b-j}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [z^b] (1+z)^b [w^{n-b}] (1+w)^{n+b} 
\sum_{j=0}^b {b\choose j} z^j w^j (1+w)^{-j}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [z^b] (1+z)^b [w^{n-b}] (1+w)^{n+b} 
\left(1+\frac{wz}{1+w}\right)^b
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [z^b] (1+z)^b [w^{n-b}] (1+w)^{n} 
(1+w+wz)^b.$$

Recalling that $n\ge b$ this becomes

$$\frac{1}{2} [z^b] (1+z)^b [w^{n-b}] (1+w)^{n} 
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} w^q (1+z)^q
\\ = \frac{1}{2} [z^b] (1+z)^b
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} {n\choose n-b-q} (1+z)^q
\\ = \frac{1}{2}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} {n\choose n-b-q} {b+q\choose b}.$$

Factoring the two binomials on the right we get

$$\frac{n!}{(n-b-q)! \times b! \times q!}
= {n\choose b} {n-b\choose q}.$$

We continue with

$$\frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} {n-b\choose q}
= \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} [z^{n-b-q}] (1+z)^{n-b}
\\ = \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b} [z^{n-b}] (1+z)^{n-b}
\sum_{q=0}^b {b\choose q} z^q
= \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b} [z^{n-b}] (1+z)^{n-b} (1+z)^b
\\ = \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}^2.$$

The piece labeled $B$ is next. We get

$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=0}^b 
{b\choose j} (-1)^{j+1}
[w^{n-b-j}] (1+w)^{n+b-j}
\\ = - \frac{1}{2} [w^{n-b}] (1+w)^{n+b}
 \sum_{j=0}^b 
{b\choose j} (-1)^{j} w^j (1+w)^{-j}
\\ = - \frac{1}{2} [w^{n-b}] (1+w)^{n+b}
\left(1-\frac{w}{1+w}\right)^b
\\ = - \frac{1}{2} [w^{n-b}] (1+w)^{n}
= - \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}.$$

We have shown that

$$A+B = \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}^2 - \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
= \frac{1}{2} {n\choose b}
\left({n\choose b} - 1\right)$$

as claimed.

**Remark.** The piece $B$ was also evaluated in the first answer.